# “alter index of table” is it modifying the table structure?

Tags: mysql

In session a, I started an uncommitted transaction.
It executes "alter table stu add index idx_name(name);".
Is this statement a modification of the table structure?
Is it will add table lock?
At the same time, I also started an uncommitted transaction in Session B to update the row data in the table.
Will Session B sql be locked by session a sql?

Comment: Depends on table engine, current table structure and precise ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: ___NOTE___ DDL commands in MySQL at least have an implicit COMMIT as part of their execution, so the ALTER will get committed

Comment: the table engine is innodb。@Akina

Comment: thank you！ RiggsFolly. I did ignore that DDL commands in MySQL have an implicit COMMIT as part of their execution. But I also want to know whether "changing the index of a table" is modifying the table structure?